# Get the network interface type on button click without continuously monitoring

Tags: ios, swift, networking, connection

In my application, there is a requirement to find the internet connection type (wifi/mobile data/ etc) on a button action and send the type along with a web service request.
I came across the apple Network framework and tried out the Network Monitor feature

```swift
func checkForInternetConnection(){
    var connectionType = ""
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "NetworkMonitor")
    let pathMonitor = NWPathMonitor()
    pathMonitor.pathUpdateHandler = {
        path in
        
        if path.usesInterfaceType(.wifi){
            connectionType = "wifi"
        }else if path.usesInterfaceType(.cellular){
            connectionType = "cellular"
        }else{
            connectionType = "other"
        }
    }
    pathMonitor.start(queue: queue)
    pathMonitor.cancel()
}
```

I don't need to continuously monitor the connection type change. I just need to check the type at the time of webservice call. For such situations, is there any other to follow?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async/await` so you can `cancel` once you have a result.

```
/// Queries `NWPathMonitor` for the `usesInterfaceType`.
/// Supported types are `NWInterface.InterfaceType.other, .cellular, .wifi, .wiredEthernet, .loopback`
/// - Returns: `String` value of the interface type, if known or an "Empty String`.`
static func connectiontype() async -> String{
    typealias Continuation = CheckedContinuation<String, Never>
    return await withCheckedContinuation({ (continuation: Continuation) in
        let monitor = NWPathMonitor()

        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            var result = ""
            for item in [NWInterface.InterfaceType.other, .cellular, .wifi, .wiredEthernet, .loopback] {
                if path.usesInterfaceType(item){
                    result = "\(item)"
                    break
                }
            }
            monitor.cancel()
            continuation.resume(returning: result)
        }
        monitor.start(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "InternetConnectionMonitor"))
    })
}
```